# Does using the same name for dataframes impact performance

Tags: performance, pyspark

Would there be any difference between the two pieces of code, performance-wise:

`df = //read the file here
 df = df.select(//some columns here)
 df = df.groupBy().agg() // some operation
 df = df.filter() //some filtering
 df.show()`

AND

`df = //read the file here
 df1 = df.select(//some columns here)
 df2 = df1.groupBy().agg() // some operation
 df3 = df2.filter() //some filtering
 df3.show()`